# foreach loop around ul list displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a foreach loop wrapped around an `ul` unordered list, the first `li` is a main topic and should be followed by items belonging to that topic.

Here is what it should look like

[image]

The word People and System are `li` with a class `nav-header`.

This is how my `ul` is displaying with other sample text for headers and items.

[image]

And this is the HTML output of my list

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">ProfileZ</li>
<li><a href="#MTIxfElrYXJpYW4tWW91dGg=.html">test</a></li>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">zetaasdf</li>
<li><a href="#MTMwfFpldGFOZXdDYW1wYWlnbjI=.html">ZetaNewCampaign2</a></li>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header">zeta</li>
<li><a href="#MTMxfGFzZGZhc2Rm.html">asdfasdf</a></li>
</ul>
</ul></ul>
```

The `ul` is repeating and nesting, the php code I used to generate the list is below.

```
<?php foreach ($profilesResults as $profilesArray) { ?>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<li class="nav-header"><?php echo $profilesArray->name; ?></li>
<?php
$campaignsObj = new Campaigns();
$campaignsResults = $campaignsObj->getCampaignsByProfileSideBar($accountID, $profilesArray->id);
foreach ($campaignsResults as $campaignsArray) {
?>
<li><a href="<?= $this->siteUrl() ?>campaign-rankings-<?= base64_encode($campaignsArray->id . "|" . str_replace(" ", "-", $campaignsArray->name)) ?>.html"><?php echo $campaignsArray->name ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

What changes should I make to get my list to display like in the first photo. Where there is only one open and close `ul` and the rest of the `li` within along with the special classed header `li`s?

Thanks

Comment: first create your $campaignsObj before the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `ul` declaration out from the first circle. It should look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
<?php foreach ($profilesResults as $profilesArray) { ?>
    <li class="nav-header"><?php echo $profilesArray->name; ?></li>
    <?php
        $campaignsObj = new Campaigns();
        $campaignsResults = $campaignsObj->getCampaignsByProfileSideBar($accountID, $profilesArray->id);
        foreach ($campaignsResults as $campaignsArray) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?= $this->siteUrl() ?>campaign-rankings-<?= base64_encode($campaignsArray->id . "|" . str_replace(" ", "-", $campaignsArray->name)) ?>.html"><?php echo $campaignsArray->name ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Jack explanation is added, give +1 back to me :)